# Exclude bin folder from .gitignore and keep it's content

Tags: git

I want my .gitignore to ignore every bin folder except the one in the PSFramework folder and keep that one's content. I managed to get the folder but its content doesn't show up.

Here is what I tried:

```
[Bb]in/
!**/PSFramework/[Bb]in/
```

Tried it with and without the slash at the end. According to what I found until now this should work but for me, it doesn't :
when i check the git status only the folder but not the files in it show up

Comment: What do you mean by "its content doesn't show up"? Where doesn't it show up. The gitignore file you show works for me locally just fine.

Comment: When i check the git status only the folder but not the files in it show up

Comment: That's normal when a folder isn't tracked by git at all: it'll just list the whole directory as untracked as opposed to each individual file within it. If you `git add wherever/PSFramework` you should see all the files in the next `git status` call.

Comment: @b0neng4 : that's just git status, which "sums up" its output by default. The option to list individual files within a directory is : `git status -uall` (it *is* explained in the doc of [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt--ultmodegt), and it *is* not obvious :) )

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Worked.

Comment: @b0neng4 : can you take 2 minutes to add the output of `git status` to your question ?